# How to retrieve values from OWL Ontology header values

Tags: owl, ontology

Can someone help in how to fetch the header values from the below sample OWL header using JenaOWLModel or OWLOntology.

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
  <owl:versionInfo>v 1.17 2003/02/26 12:56:51 mdean</owl:versionInfo>
  <rdfs:comment>An example ontology</rdfs:comment>
  <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/foo"/>
</owl:Ontology>

You can refer http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Annotations (2.2. Ontology Headers) for more reference.

I tried using the below code to fetch the values, but not able to fetch the values. I can just see the keys. Any help would be appreciated.



        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology owlLOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(dataPath));
    Set owlAnnotationPropertySet = owlLOntology.getAnnotationPropertiesInSignature();
    Iterator<OWLAnnotationProperty> iter = owlAnnotationPropertySet.iterator();while(iter.hasNext()){   
        OWLAnnotationProperty owlAnnotationProperty = (OWLAnnotationProperty) iter.next();    
    }
```

Thanks
Anurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OWL API you can get the ontology IRI (the contents of the rdf:about tag) and version info by using

```
owlLOntology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI();
```

and

```
owlLOntology.getOntologyID().getVersionInfo();
```

For the annotations you can try

```
for (OWLAnnotation annontation: o.getAnnotations() {
 annotation.getValue();
}
```

to get the values for each annotation property. As for imports try 
`owlLOntology.getImports();`

Comment: Any idea how to get the value of the creator below
<dc:creator rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Creator Name</dc:creator>

Comment: `<dc:creator rdf:datatype="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"; >Creator Name</dc:creator> ` would be an annotation of your ontology. So iterating over each annotation should return that. See edited answer for some code on how to achieve this.